# Google Wallet digital goods API - notification on success

Tags: android-pay

It appears that I have been able to successfully implement the Google Wallet Digital Goods API onto my site.

Whilst testing on the sandbox environment and with regards to notifications from Google to the buyer, i'm observing:

Cancellations - They receive an email with every cancelled transaction (perfect).
Purchases - Not received or infrequent. (Why so?)

Should I expect anything different in production?

Comment: That would be odd - I do get emails for successful sandbox buyer purchases...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. I see the following in the merchant center..."You received a new order. Google has sent the customer an order confirmation email." But, can't find it for the life of me. Double checking..

Comment: You _are_ using a different email address for the _sandbox buyer account_ right? You should be, otherwise, it would fail (re: can't buy from yourself")....

Comment: Yes, I have created brand new accounts. I just tested a new merchant account, using a new gmail (customer). Neither account receives an email on success. When I go to the merchant center, I see the order with a status of Charged. When I refund the order, I get an email, but with absolutely no order or refund information contained, i.e. no refund amount - it makes no sense.

Comment: Can now reproduce this. Am not a Googler so this can only be answered by them. I do see the order in my sandbox buyer Orders. Can't even get to my Sandbox merchant page at this time....

Comment: To add (for Googlers): reported this by email as well - I'm seeing _sandbox_ orders (mixed) in my _production_ (new) Merchant Center. Seems this happened recently. Clicking on the _sandbox_ order generates error.

Comment: Must be from the Checkout turn down.  Let me see what's going on.

Comment: Ed, can you take a screen shot and email me?